# My SQL full text search error in searching multiple columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using the following query in my questions database attached image:
[image]

```
SELECT *, MATCH(question,short_answer,long_answer) AGAINST('transmission impairment') AS Score
FROM questions
WHERE MATCH(question,short_answer,long_answer) AGAINST('transmission impairment')
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

and I am getting the following errors[image]:

Comment: which mysql version are you using? NB: MySQL 5.6 supports full text searches on InnoDB tables

Comment: I am using Xampp with Apache 2.4.17, MariaDB 10.1.13, PHP 5.6.23, phpMyAdmin 4.5.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2, XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.2, Webalizer 2.23-04, Mercury Mail Transport System 4.63, FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.41, Tomcat 7.0.56 (with mod_proxy_ajp as connector), Strawberry Perl 7.0.56 Portable

Comment: please check your table storage `Engine` using this query `SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE Name = 'questions';`

Comment: It is MyISAM  Dynamic database

Comment: I am able to execute the query with single column eg `SELECT *, MATCH(long_answer) AGAINST('transmission impairment') AS Score FROM questions WHERE MATCH(long_answer) AGAINST('transmission impairment') ORDER BY score DESC` works fine

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me :

```
SELECT *, MATCH(long_answer) AGAINST('guided media') AS Score FROM questions WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM questions WHERE MATCH(long_answer) AGAINST('guided media') UNION SELECT id FROM questions WHERE MATCH(question) AGAINST('guided media') ) ORDER BY score DESC
```

I still don't feel this to be optimal solution